# Multiple ReturnUrl parameters appearing after automatic redirect to Login action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, membershipreboot

I'm in the process of converting an MVC5 app to OWIN. To get automatic redirection on unauthorized access, I set the `LoginPath` on `CookieAuthenticationOptions` and set `<authentication mode="None" />` and `<modules><remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" /></modules>` in web.config.

When I try to access `example.com/AppName/` it is successfully redirecting to the LoginPath `example.com/AppName/Account/Login` but it's adding in multiple `ReturnUrl` parameters to the query string.

eg. `example.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAppName%2F%3FReturnUrl%3D%252fAppName%252f`

How do I stop it from adding in multiple ReturnUrl parameters?